# What would the regular expression for this situation be?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm pretty new to `JavaScript`, and I've been trying to figure out the `regular expression` for this for a while.
I need to validate a user entry in the form of `"mm/yy"`.

The 1st digit of the month must be `0` or `1`. If it is `0` then the 2nd digit can be from `1` to `9`. If it is `1`, then the second digit can be `0` to `2`. The year can be `14` to `19`. It must have the slash.

This is what I have so far:

```
var reExp = /^0(?=\d)|1(?=1)|2\/14$/; //RegExp for expiry


if ($('expiry').value.search(reExp)==-1){
    $('expiry').value = ''; 
    $('expiryMsg').style.fontSize="10px";
    $('expiryMsg').innerHTML = "Invalid Entry: Must be a valid expiry date.";
}
else {
    $('expiryMsg').innerHTML = "*";
    $('expiryMsg').style.fontSize="16px";
}
```

I want to do all the validation in one expression, is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens next year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
/^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/1[4-9]$/
```

Comment: @SeattleLeonard: Not really but it avoids to create a capturing group and to record the substring matched by this capturing group.